# Find value inside a collection in mongoose from nested json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose I have data stored in collection **Teacher** as:

```
{
    "name":"john",
    "age":45,
    "class_access":{
        1234:"head",
        1235:"head
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("12312312"),
}

{
    "name":"henry",
    "age":55,
    "class_access":{
        1234:"head",
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("sdf9991"),
}

{
    "name":"travis",
    "age":35,
    "class_access":{
        2341:"head",
    },
    "_id" : ObjectId("sas21"),
}
```

I want to find all the information of all the teachers belonging to class 1234.

For this I tried:

```
 const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ class_access: {1234:"head"} })
```

But it doesn't return anything.
So how can I access nested json to get all the details?

If any one needs any further information do let me know.

As per solution provided by Mr. Arif
const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ "class_access.1234": "head" });

Support class value is not constant say I'm getting it from variable

```
const className = 1234
```

Now if I try, fetching className, it gives syntax error, I tried following syntax error for all of them

const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ class_access.className: "head" });

const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ class_access[className]: "head" });

const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ 'class_access.+'${className}': "head" });

So how can we do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `class_access` represent object which may have multiple keys, you should try like

You can use `[variableName]` as key like following

**method 1: Using string template**

```
const className = 1234
const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ [`class_access.${className }`]: "head" });
```

**method 2: Using string concatenation**

```
const className = 1234
const classAccess = 'class_access.' + className;
const TeacherDetails = await Teacher.find({ [classAccess] : "head" });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have edited the question , could you please have a look. As it doesn't satisfy my usage

Comment: @SivaPradhan check the updated answer, hope this will help you